# How to make 3D model of heat equation in Python?

Tags: python, fft, differential-equations

> Given:

[image]

and

> We have formula:

[image]

I make 3D model, but I can't give the condition like **when x = 0 u(0,t) = 0**

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
def u(x,t,n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        alpha=((6*(-1)**i-30)/(i**2*np.pi**2))
        e=np.exp((-(np.pi**2)*(i**2)*t))
        sin=np.sin((i*np.pi*x)/3)
        u=alpha*e*sin
    return u

N=20
L = 4  # length
att = 20 # iteration

x = np.linspace(0, L ,N) #x-array
t = np.linspace(0, L, N) #t-array
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, t)

Z = u(X, Y, att)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=1000)
plt.show()
```

> My 3D model:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you actually computed a sum in the partial Fourier sum calculation, at the moment you just return the last term of that sum.

```py
def u(x,t,n):
    u = 0*x
    for i in range(1,n):
        alpha=((6*(-1)**i-30)/(i**2*np.pi**2))
        e=np.exp((-(np.pi**2)*(i**2)*t))
        sin=np.sin((i*np.pi*x)/3)
        u+=alpha*e*sin
    return u
```

Are you sure about the Fourier coefficients? The number `30` in it is for me somewhat suspicious. Also the frequency seems strange, the continuation of `u(x,0)` should be an odd rectangular wave of period 8. Notice, it is `a=3` but `L=4`.

Comment: Ohhh god, thaank you. I forget change values of alpha, e, and sin. That's my fault